# Can affinity analysis be used for identifying other types of correlation besides purchases?

Tags: correlation, apriori

I made a questionnaire where respondents were asked to select up to 5 hurdles they consider to be the most significant for BI (business intelligence) initiatives in the cloud.

Now I would like to analyse the correlation between all these selections. I have placed the answers to all of these questions in a long format, like this:

[image]

I was wondering if an affinity analysis (aka: "market-basket" analysis) could be used for this purpose? I tried using the market-basket node in SAS Enterprise Miner and I did see some expected correlation. For instance between security of endpoints in BI cloud initiatives (SECEP) and policies and regulations around data (PLDATA).

Someone told me that market basket analysis only applies to purchase of products and services, but I am unconvinced. After all how can math differentiate what I am trying to associate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed up with other statisticians, who assured me that my doubts were pertinent and I can in fact use a "market-basket" analysis for this.